# ios FMDB SELECT NOT IN (?)

Tags: ios, select, fmdb

I would like to check if an id list is in the database.
Here is my code...

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
NSString *string = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
FMResultSet * rs = [self.db executeQuery:@"SELECT id FROM FriendList WHERE id NOT IN (?)",string];
```

It's doesn't work. It's only work if array only has a single number.

Anyone knows how to do SELECT NOT IN using FMDB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need little modification here.

Follow below code.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
NSString *components = [array componentsJoinedByString:@", "];


NSMutableString *valueString = [NSMutableString new];

NSMutableString *fieldString = [NSMutableString new];

[fieldString appendString:@"SELECT id FROM FriendList WHERE id NOT IN ("];

for (NSString *fielValue in array) {
    [fieldString appendString:@"?,"];
    [valueString appendString:fielValue];
}

[fieldString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([fieldString length] - 1, 1) withString:@")"];
NSString *normalString = [NSString stringWithString:fieldString];
fieldString = nil;

FMResultSet * rs = [self.db executeQuery:@"%@", normalString, components];
```

**EDIT:**

From the information you provide me in a comments, I did figure out that `sqlite` is not able to compile the string literal while you provide multiple items from array components. I modify answer still it's from your end to test that it is working or not? Leave a comment for acknowledgment.

Comment: I have tested it. It's working on my side. What issues have you got?

Comment: sorry, I found that your code actually works. But the object in my array is actually like @"54633a47b51ed30aa5f6891e". Console shows "unrecognized token: "54656cdca7bc96aac023e6a3"". Do you know why is that?

Comment: I guess that `id` field in table is `INTEGER`. And this is a string value in array. Can you use other field to store array value?

Comment: id field in table is TEXT~~~

Comment: I got the reason. Because string literal not recognised by `sqlite` here. I'll provide you edited answer

Comment: The result is that it's only work if array only has a single number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65060/discussion-between-kampai-and-jenny).